# How to add a button to Excel with OLE

Tags: delphi, excel, ole, ole-automation

I use OLE method like this:

```
var   
  xlApp, xlWorkBook, xlWorkSheet, arr: Variant; 
begin   
  xlApp := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');   
  xlApp.Visible := True;    
end;
```

How to add a button to Excel?

And how to assign a exist marco on this button?

Where can I find Delphi-OLE-Office document?

Thx.

Comment: See [Deborah Pate's Automation Pages](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/Automation.htm) for useful info about using OLE automation with Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out by recording a VBA macro and then pasting it into your Delphi routine:

```
xlApp := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
xlApp.Visible := True;
xlWorkBook := xlApp.Workbooks.Add;
xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(10, 10, 80, 30).Select;
xlWorkBook.Selection.OnAction := 'Macro1';
```

There is no Delphi documentation of Office COM automation. You have to use the MSDN documentation and translate it into Delphi yourself.

Comment: I does not work for me. The error _OLE: Method 'Selection' not found_ pops up.